# JS doesn't read XML

Tags: php, javascript, xml, google-maps

I have a PHP file which creates a XML file and a JS file which reads the XML file. When I press a button in HTML, it redirects me to the PHP file which does create the XML file, but the JS file doesn't read it.

```
GDownloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxm1l.php", function(data) {
  var xml = GXml.parse(data);
  var markerid = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markerid.length; i++) {
    var type = markerid[i].getAttribute("type");
    //var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markerid[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                            //parseFloat(markerid[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var date = markerid[i].getAttribute("date");

    var punktx = markerid[i].getAttribute("point");
    var punkt = punktx.toString();
    var temp = new Array();
    temp = punkt.split(",");
    var point = new GLatLng(temp[0],temp[1])


    var marker = createMarker(point, date, type);
    map.addOverlay(marker);
  }
});
```

How to solve this issue? this JS script should take data from XML file and make markers on my Google Maps, but the JS file won't start or something.

Comment: What does the XML that your PHP script generates look like?  Did you try validating the XML output in the W3 XML validator?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried viewing the XML feed you mentioned in the comments for the question, I got the following:

> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location:
>   http://www.liiklusinfo.ee/proov4/phpsqlajax_genxm1l.php Line Number 1,
>   Column 1: 
>   ^

You can't parse invalid XML feeds.  With HTML browsers are supposed to try and parse invalid markup, but with XML, the proper behaviour is to abort and fail if the markup is invalid.

Try fixing the problems with your XML feed first, maybe you'll have more luck parsing it then.

There's an XML validator at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp which should be of help in identifying what's wrong with your feed.

Comment: To view the XML file, you must go to http://www.liiklusinfo.ee/proov5/ and click "30 minutit" to view data entered 1 hour ago or "kõik" to view all the data. But the problem remains the same. I think it's because I have onLoad function in HTML body, which starts the JS, but the button function is after the body load. How to bring the button load in front of body load?

Comment: Basically I have come to a resolution, that I need to know how to activate part of javascript when XML is created. The part which is given above. The whole JS file is located at http://www.liiklusinfo.ee/proov5/script.js

Comment: So, any ideas on how to sort markers by date? Can I take marker values from the XML table based on date?

Comment: sorry but I wouldn't be able to help with that, I suggest you try googling for it, and if you don't find anything then you can always ask another question.  I'd just be inclined to generate the XML file in the order I needed it.